# Proving a statement about perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, solution-verification

The statement I want to prove is the following:

> $9+108x^2(1+x)$ is never a perfect square besides $x=0\space\wedge\space x=\pm1\space\wedge\space x=4\space\wedge\space x=6$.

---

**My Work**

Let's name the number: $\text{n}=9+108x^2(1+x)$. Because it must be a perfect square we can write: $\text{n}^2=9+108x^2(1+x)$ (where $\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$). Let's divide both sides by $9$: $\frac{\text{n}^2}{9}=1+12x^2(1+x)$. Now, $\frac{\text{n}^2}{9}=\left(\frac{\text{n}}{3}\right)^2$ is just another integer and perfect square. So we can write $\left(\frac{\text{n}}{3}\right)^2=\text{p}^2$ (where $\text{p}\in\mathbb{Z}$). So we have:

$$\text{p}^2=1+12x^2(1+x)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{p}^2-1=12x^2(1+x)\tag1$$

Now, we know that $\text{p}^2-1=(\text{p}+1)(\text{p}-1)$. So we can write:

$$(\text{p}+1)(\text{p}-1)=12x^2(1+x)\tag2$$

Suppose $x$ is an even number: $x=\text{m}\cdot2^\text{k}$ (where $\text{m}$ is odd). We get:

$$(\text{p}+1)(\text{p}-1)=12\left(\text{m}\cdot2^\text{k}\right)^2\left(1+\text{m}\cdot2^\text{k}\right)=3\cdot4^{1+\text{k}}\text{m}^2\left(1+\text{m}\cdot2^\text{k}\right)\tag3$$

Then we need to have $\text{m}^2\text{|}\text{p}\pm1$, such that $\text{p}=\pm1+\text{hm}^2$ (where $\text{h}\in\mathbb{Z}$). So we can write:

$$\text{h}^2\text{m}^2\pm2\text{h}=3\cdot4^{1+\text{k}}\text{m}^2\left(1+\text{m}\cdot2^\text{k}\right)\tag4$$

Which is the same as (because $2^x\cdot4^{1+x}=2^{2+3x}$ and $\text{m}\ne0$):

$$\text{h}^2\pm2\text{h}-3\cdot2^{2+3\text{k}}\text{m}-3\cdot4^{1+\text{k}}=0\tag5$$

Can someone help me finish the proof?

Comment: I ran a python program for your statement checking for x upto 10^6, it produced extra results which states x can also be 87722,
88751,
89786,
90827,
91874,
92927,
93986,
95051,
96122,
97199,
98282,
99371,
100466. So, I guess you have to restrict the domain.

Comment: @John that is wrong, I did the same thing using Mathematica and I only found the ones I mention in my question.

Comment: @John  Are you sure of your numbers?  Here is [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5B1%2B12*87722%5E2*%281%2B87722%29%5D) on $87722$, for example.

Comment: @lulu, I am extremely sorry, the program is ignoring the first 3 $0$s, and btw, it's 9+. Thanks for notifying me ! :)

Comment: @John  no worries.

Comment: Why not factor out a 9

Comment: Equations of the form $y^2$ equals a cubic in $x$ generally lead to elliptic curves and are rarely solvable by entirely elementary means. If you search around, you can probably find some earlier question about such equations on this site.

Comment: You shouldn't use logical symbols here: $x=0\space\wedge\space x=6$ is a logical impossibility. Just say "...besides $x=0$ and..."

Comment: @GerryMyerson Any idea if I can use elementary means on this one?

Comment: I don't know. I doubt it. Where did the equation come from?

Comment: @GerryMyerson from a bigger problem I'm working on.

Comment: off topic: is there a reason you use text variables instead of normal math mode variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a constant $\, D := 108,\,$ consider the function defined by
$$ f(x,y) := 9 + D\,x^2(1+x) - y^2 \tag{1} $$
where $\, f(x,y) = 0\,$ is the equation of an elliptic curve.
It is equivalent to the curve in Weierstrass form
$$ E: y^2 = x^3 + 1/D\,x^2 + 12/D^3 \tag{2} $$
in the following sense. $\,f(x,y) = 0 \,$ iff $\,[x/D,y/D^2]\,$ is
a point of curve $\,E\,$
which has $j$-invariant equal to $\,-12288/25.\,$
This curve is equivalent to the [LMFDB 135.a1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/135/a/) curve
$$ E135a: y^2 + y = x^3 - 3x + 4. \tag{3} $$
The curve $\,E\,$ has a rational point $\,P:=[1/D,15/D^2]\,$ of rank $\,1\,$ which PARI/GP seems not to be able to provide, but it **does**
provide a rational generating point $\,[4,-8]\,$ for curve $\,E135a\,$.
Given a point $\,[x,y]\,$ of $\,E135a\,$ then
$\,[(x-1)/(3D),(-2y-1)/D^2]\,$ is a point of $\,E.\,$
Each point $\,[x,y]\,$ of $\,E\,$ satisfies 
$$ 0 = f(x\, D,y\, D^2). \tag{4} $$
However there are only a finite number of integer solutions to $\,f(x,y)=0.\,$
They correspond to the generator multiples
$$ 1P\mapsto(1,15),\, 2P\mapsto(0,3),\, 4P\mapsto(-1,-3),\, 7P\mapsto(6,-135),\,
 8P\mapsto(4,93). \tag{5}$$
Each solution $\,(x,y)\,$ yields a solution $\,(x,-y).\,$ There
are no other solutions in integers.

Some [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code is

```
D = 108; E = ellinit([0,1/D,0,0,1/12/D^2]); P = [1/D,15/D^2];
E135a = ellinit([0, 0, 1, -3, 4]);
print("E:",ellgenerators(E));
print("E135a:",ellgenerators(E135a));
for(n=1, 9, print(n," ",[x,y]=ellmul(E,P,n); [x*D,y*D^2]));
```

Comment: Where did you find the solutions to the integral points?

Comment: @Jan It comes from the theory of elliptic curves. In PARI/GP I used `ellgenerators(E135a)`.

Comment: can you show me how I can find those, using a link or something? Thanks for your help already.

Comment: because I can't find them

Comment: Is there a way to prove the same for the function $81 + 60 x (1 + x) (-2 + 5 x)$

Comment: @jan As I wrote in my answer, $f(x,y)=0$ **is** an elliptic curve equivalent to the two others I wrote about and the same elliptic theory holds for all of them.

Comment: But the elliptic curve I get for that function is different, or not?